# Arrow drawn to \tikzmark node inside \sqrt goes off the page

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikzmark

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{aligned}
    \tikzmark{wexponent}{Wurzelexponent} && \\[1em]
     \sqrt[{\tikzmark{nwex}{n}}]{\tikzmark{aradi}{a}} & = \tikzmark{xwter}{x} \\[1em] %radikand will nicht pfeilen-----------------
      \tikzmark{radikand}{Radikand} && \tikzmark{wterm}{Wurzelterm}\\[1em]
      (-2)^2 & =\sqrt[2]4\neq -2
    \end{aligned}
    \phantom{\hspace{88.5mm}}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (wexponent.south) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{$ $}(nwex.north);}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (radikand.north) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{$ $}(aradi.south);}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (wterm.north) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{$ $}(xwter.east);}
  \end{equation*} 


\end{document}
```

Why does this arrow from "Radikand" to inside of the base of the `\sqrt` go to the wrong place?

[image: kgklj]

Comment: `\sqrt[x][{y}` uses `\mathpalette`.  This typesets the contents four times but only leaves the correct instance in the document.  This might break your code here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, your custom `\tikzmark` REALLY doesn't like being inside `\sqrt`.  Using `\sbox` causes `\tikzmark` to execute outside `\sqrt` but be displayed inside.  The change to `tikzpicture` outside the `equation*` isn't really necessary, but does reduce the number of `\pgfsyspdfmark` entries in the aux file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]%
{\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{aligned}
    \tikzmark{wexponent}{Wurzelexponent} && \\[1em]
     \sbox1{\tikzmark{aradi}{a}}%
     \sqrt[{\tikzmark{nwex}{n}}]{\usebox1} & = \tikzmark{xwter}{x} \\[1em] %radikand will nicht pfeilen-----------------
      \tikzmark{radikand}{Radikand} && \tikzmark{wterm}{Wurzelterm}\\[1em]
      (-2)^2 & =\sqrt[2]4\neq -2
    \end{aligned}
    \phantom{\hspace{88.5mm}}
  \end{equation*} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (wexponent.south) to [bend left=0] (nwex.north);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (radikand.north) to [bend left=0] (aradi.south);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (wterm.north) to [bend left=0] (xwter.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

If you are going to be doing this a lot, you might find the `\mathtikzmark` macro below useful.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]%
{\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt] (#1) {#2};}}

\usepackage{mathstyle}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[2]{%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]%
{\node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=2pt] (#1) {$\m@th\currentmathstyle#2$};}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
   \begin{aligned}
    \tikzmark{wexponent}{Wurzelexponent} && \\[1em]
     \sbox1{\tikzmark{aradi}{$a$}}%
     \sqrt[{\mathtikzmark{nwex}{n}}]{\usebox1} & = \mathtikzmark{xwter}{x} \\[1em] %radikand will nicht pfeilen-----------------
      \tikzmark{radikand}{Radikand} && \tikzmark{wterm}{Wurzelterm}\\[1em]
      (-2)^2 & =\sqrt[2]4\neq -2
    \end{aligned}
    \phantom{\hspace{88.5mm}}
  \end{equation*} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (wexponent.south) to [bend left=0] (nwex.north);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (radikand.north) to [bend left=0] (aradi.south);
    \draw[blue,thick,->] (wterm.north) to [bend left=0] (xwter.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```